# Forward dependencies @startdate @enddate=@startdate + 1 Week

Tags: sql, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, parameters

Im looking for a way if the user selects

```
@startdate = '12-01-2015'
then
@enddate = @startdate + 1 Week
```

this is for my parameter, but please be aware my report is a matrix and uses each week for a sample of data so the parameter needs to automatically select
its enddate from all startdates selected

i.e

startdates in ( '12-01-2015', '19-01-2015')

then endate in ( '18-01-2015', '26-01-2015')

this is what im using for my startdate parameter

```
select distinct
CAST(startdate AS DATE) as Startdate
FROM [Calendar] 
where DatePart(YEAR,startdate)  >= 2014
order by 1 asc
```

Comment: `Dateadd(Week,1,@startdate )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATEADD`

```
@startdate = '12-01-2015'
then
@enddate = DATEADD(wk, 1, @startdate)
```

or if startdate variable has `DATE/DATETIME` type

```
@startdate = '12-01-2015'
then
@enddate = @startdate + 7;   -- Implicit cast add 7 days
```

EDIT:

```
select distinct
    CAST(startdate AS DATE) as Startdate,
    DATEADD(wk, 1, CAST(startdate AS DATE)) as EndDate
FROM [Calendar] 
where DatePart(YEAR,startdate)  >= 2014
order by 1 asc
```

Comment: how do i write this as the select for my parameter 
as the start-date wont be pre defined so the user would select the startdate 

i.e can you write me the select statement that will add 7 days on to any date passed into {@startdate}

Comment: Cheers bro appriciate your time